# WCSession fails to activate on paired watch and phone simulators

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, watchos, watchconnectivity

Overview:

- I am building a very simple Apple Watch and iPhone app
- I am running/debugging the apps using the watch and phone simulators in Xcode
- I am using WatchConnectivity to make them communicate
- **I cannot activate a `WCSession` on either the watch or phone simulators although they are paired**

In the Xcode Devices window, my watch simulator and phone simulator are paired. I am able to launch my watch app using the WatchKit App scheme (which also launches the phone simulator but doesn't open the mobile app). I then launch my mobile app by clicking on the app icon on the phone simulator.

Mobile app:

- `ViewController` implements `WCSessionDelegate`
- WatchConnectivity session is activated in the `viewDidLoad` method

Watch app:

- `InterfaceController` implements `WCSessionDelegate`
- WatchConnectivity session is activated in the `willActivate` method

When I run the WatchKit app, the following message is logged:

```
[WC] WCSession has not been activated
```

When I then open the mobile app by clicking on the app icon, I get the following messages:

```
[WC] WCSession has not been activated
Apple Watch is not paired
[WC] WCSession has not been activated
WatchKit app is not installed on the paired watch
```

(I added logging statements to display the result of checking `isPaired` and `isWatchAppInstalled` on the session in the mobile app)

My `WCSession` activation code is the same in my mobile app and watch app:

```
if ([WCSession isSupported]) {
  WCSession *session = [WCSession defaultSession];
  session.delegate = self;
  [session activateSession];
  // print debugging statements about paired watch, etc.
}
```

Does anyone know why WatchConnectivity doesn't detect the fact that the phone and watch simulators are paired? Why doesn't the `WCSession` get activated?

Comment: You can try to clean all and then close iphone and watch simulator and restart.

Comment: I would try to hold reference to WCSession.